# MVC Passing Attribute as Argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a shopping cart but when  try to pass Id as an argument this is what happen

http://localhost:15359/RealCartController/Order/FinalProject.Models.Clothes

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

this is in RealCartController

```
   public ActionResult Order(int id)
            {
                if(Session["cart"] == null)
                {
                    List<Item> cloth = new List<Item>();
                    cloth.Add(new Item(de.Clothes.Find(id),1));
                    Session["cart"] = cloth;
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
                    int index = isExisting(id);
                    if (index == -1)
                        cart.Add(new Item(de.Clothes.Find(id), 1));
                    else
                        cart[index].Amount++;

                    Session["cart"] = cart;
                }
                return View();
            }
```

This is in the View that calls the function

```
@if (Model != null)
{

    foreach (Clothes Id in Model)
    {
        if (Id.Amount > 0)
        {

        <div id="container">
            <div id="row">

                <img src="~/Content/img/@Html.DisplayFor(model => Id.ImagePath)" style="height:200px;width:200px;" />
                <br />
                <br />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "Order", "RealCartController", new { id = Id }, null);
            </div>
        </div>
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the View of the function

```
@foreach (Item item in (List<Item>)Session["cart"])
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@item.Cl.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Cl.Price</td>
                <td>@item.Cl.Amount</td>
                <td>@item.Cl.Price * item.Cl.Amount</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: I confirm the link provided gives a 404 error :=)

Comment: The link is pointing to *localhost*, which is located on the local machine. If we don't have the settings configured or files properly located in our machines, we can't test the validity of it. :-\

Comment: @LaurentLequenne and Sometowngeek it formats it automatic as a link and the information in the url is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Id` in this line `foreach (Clothes Id in Model)` is an object and not an number. When you try to send an object as an argument with the `ActionLink` function it will just send the objects class name. Therefore the api call fails to parse the parameter.

You can see that an class name is send in the url.

> http://localhost:15359/RealCartController/Order/FinalProject.Models.Clothes

The `FinalProject.Models.Clothes` part should be the orders id number instead.

> http://localhost:15359/RealCartController/Order/1

Answer (score 0):

it should look like something like this

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "Order", "RealCartController", new { id = 
    Id.ProductId }, null);
```

ProductId  is From your class/model and is your Primary Key of the Items